# The 'Filter' Button in the 'Timeline' tab of Chrome's Developer tools is inactive.

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using the timeline view in Chrome's Developer Tools to try to learn about performance optimization, but the 'filter' button at the bottom-left grid (I can attach a picture if necessary -- it's in between the 'clear recording' and 'collect garbage' icons) that is used to filter events seems to be permanently grayed.  Any instance of chrome that I have open won't allow me to use this feature, this button is gray (inactive) though the other buttons (like record, clear recording, and collect garbage, as well as the various views) are working properly.  Any insights as to why this might be?  I can't use filter even when I have a timeline trace freshly recorded with many different types of events.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Turn off Flame View!  Filter can't be used if Flame View is on.

Comment: what if filter button is not visible in console tab?